# Replacing an element value in an array using const and let in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, radio-button

I have 10 radio buttons, where I can select only one. On selecting a radio button, the boolean value changes to true from false with respect to its id value.

And if the user changes the selected value, then that particular index value of boolean array must change to true, by changing the previously selected value to false, likewise it goes on...

How to do it in react?

```
 let questions;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    this.state = {
      btnDisabled: true,
      questions: [],
    };
    this.changeRadioHandler = this.changeRadioHandler.bind(this);
    this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
  }

  changeRadioHandler = (event) => {
    const qn = event.target.name;    
    let text = this.props.data.matrix.options;
    let userAnswer = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
      userAnswer.push(false);      
    }
    const options = text.map((t, index) => ({
      text: t.text,
      userAnswer: userAnswer[index],
    }));    
    console.log(options);
    const question = {
      id: event.target.value,
      qn,
      options,
    };
    if (this.state.questions.some((question) => question.qn === qn)) {
      questions = [
        ...this.state.questions.filter((question) => question.qn !== qn),
        question,
      ];
      console.log("if loop", questions);
    } else {
      questions = [...this.state.questions, question];
    }
    this.setState({ questions });
    console.log(questions);
    if (questions.length === 10) {
      this.setState({
        btnDisabled: false,
      });
    }
  };

  submitHandler = () => {    
    console.log("btn clkd", questions);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="matrix-bd">
        {this.props.data.header_text && (
          <div class="header-qn">
            <h5>{this.props.data.header_text} </h5>
          </div>
        )}
        {this.props.data.matrix && (
          <div class="grid">
            {this.props.data.matrix.option_questions.map((questions, j) => {
              return (
                <div class="rows" key={j}>
                  <div class="cell main">{questions.text}</div>
                  {this.props.data.matrix.options.map((element, i) => {
                    return (
                      <div class="cell" key={i}>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          id={"rad" + j + i}
                          name={questions.text}
                          value={element.text}
                          onChange={this.changeRadioHandler}
                        ></input>
                        <label htmlFor={"rad" + j + i}>{element.text}</label>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        )}
        <div class="buttonsubmit text-right">
          <button
            type="button"
            id="QstnSubmit"
            name="QstnSubmit"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            disabled={this.state.btnDisabled}
            onClick={this.submitHandler}
          >
            {this.props.labels.LBLSUBMIT}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my object array goes like this...

```
options: Array(10)
0: {text: "1", userAnswer: false}
1: {text: "2", userAnswer: false}
2: {text: "3", userAnswer: false}
3: {text: "4", userAnswer: false}
4: {text: "5", userAnswer: false}
5: {text: "6", userAnswer: false}
6: {text: "7", userAnswer: false}
7: {text: "8", userAnswer: false}
8: {text: "9", userAnswer: false}
9: {text: "10", userAnswer: false}
length: 10
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you run the code? You're just setting every index in the boolean array to false.

Comment: Can you update and include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: I have added the full code

Comment: Perhaps you can try explaining what this code is doing, and what you *think* it should do. As-is, the radio input values are set from the `props.data.matrix.option` array, so if you want to toggle the selected radio input you need to update the props passed in. Can you provide a *more* complete code example, perhaps a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue, and provide a set of reproduction steps?

Answer (score 0):

```
changeRadioHandler = (event) => {
    const qn = event.target.name;
    const id = event.target.value;
    let text = this.props.data.matrix.options;
    let userAnswer = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
      userAnswer.push(false);
    }
    const option = text.map((t, index) => ({
      text: t.text,
      userAnswer: userAnswer[index],
    }));
    const elIndex = option.findIndex((element, i) => element.text === id);
    let options = [...option];
    options[elIndex] = {
      ...options[elIndex],
      userAnswer: true,
    };
    const question = {
      id: event.target.value,
      qn,
      options,
    };
    if (this.state.questions.some((question) => question.qn === qn)) {
      questions = [
        ...this.state.questions.filter((question) => question.qn !== qn),
        question,
      ];
    } else {
      questions = [...this.state.questions, question];
    }
    this.setState({ questions });
    console.log(questions);
    if (questions.length === 10) {
      this.setState({
        btnDisabled: false,
      });
    }
  };
```